# Team Foundation Server Build Agent missing some capabilities - how to add?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have TFS2018 with VS2019 installed on my Build Server.  I have just added a default build agent but am getting a missing capabilities error when trying to queue a new build.

Checking the capabilities tab on the agent, I can see I am missing the VisualStudio capability.  The build one also references appears to be there (points to msbuild 14).

Can anyone tell me what the capabilities (and paths) should be for visual studio 2019.   I assume one is called VisualStudio and should point to a directory somewhere.  I also understand there should be one called VisualStudo_16 or something like that.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please double check and make sure you have indeed installed the VS2019 on your build server.

Then try to restart the agent services (run `services.msc` to open the services console ), basically it will scan and identify the capabilities again. 
If that still not work, then you can try to add user-defined capabilities manually:

Navigate to the Agent Pool and select the specific agent  (`http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentPool`) -> Capabilities -> Add Capability -> Add the following VS 2019 capabilities (community version for example):

[image]

[image]

Comment: The important step is to restart the agent like Andy said.  The capabilities should all light up after.

Comment: Thanks, it was not picking up VS, so I added the capabilities manually. I assume that '##[warning]Visual Studio was not found. Try installing a supported version of Visual Studio'   is occurring because the solution (sln) file was originally developed on an earlier version of Visual Studio (in this case 15).